# how to use setCommandClass() with MultiActionController in Spring MVC 2.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am moving forward from Struts2 controllers to Spring MVC 2.5

In case of Struts2 OGNL used to take care of populating the property of Action class. Here in Spring MVC 2.5 also they have a `SimpleFormController` which can call the `setCommandClass(UserDefinedBean.class)` in the constructor to auto-populate property of the bean class from parameters.

But in case of `MultiActionController` (this seems very useful for my requirement) I am doing `request.getParameter("paramName");` to get parameters from request. Is there any way to utilize the `setCommandClass()` with `MultiActionController`?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `MultiActionController` rather than annotated controllers?

Comment: @axtavt , I'm pretty new with Spring MVC. Googling the words "annotated controllers" found some results. Let me go through the posts and come back to you. I guess(not sure if it is right) "annotated controllers" wont be populating fields automatically unless I define for each and every parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the command object as one of the argument in your action method, eg:

```
public (ModelAndView | Map | String | void) actionName(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object commandObject);
```

For extensive use of data binding you can always override the
[initBinder(...)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/MultiActionController.html#initBinder%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder%29) method to have your custom binding and validators.

Between why using Spring 2.5.x ? Why not Spring 3.0.x ? You have more flexibility in the new version by using annotations. Even Spring doesn't recommend using the old method of extending Controllers. Just a suggestion as I am not sure about your design or requirement.